# window.atob fails: "string to be decoded is not correctly encoded" on strings of specific lengths

Tags: javascript, base64, domexception

Tried `window.atob(x);` where `x` is `"A"`, `"AA"`, `"AAA"`, and so forth.
Why does the browser say:

> VM156:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window':
>   The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

when the string length is 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, ...

```js
["A","AA","AAA","AAAA","AAAAA","AAAAAA","AAAAAAA"].forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str.length,str);
  try {
    console.log(atob(str));
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Hi, if you could enlighten me on how the mozilla developer documentation answers the above question please?

Comment: Perhaps it would help. I cannot reproduce the issue with the details given

Comment: Hex strings need to be even length

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce it all the time by typing: x="A"; window.atob(x); in the console of my google chrome browser. As for even vs odd, the exception does not occur when x is "AAA", so odd lengths are fine. I'm still puzzled by this problem.

Comment: I assume it is because A and AAAAA is not valid b64 encoded data.